How can I re-enable Bitbucket issues in an Atlassian workspace?
https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/understand-bitbucket-issues/
writes that

Bitbucket issue tracker is not available in all workspaces

"Issue Tracker is not supported in workspaces administered through admin.atlassian.com. The Issue Tracker and issues will be disabled when you create or following a transfer to a workspace administered through admin.atlassian.com. If you have already transferred the repository, you can transfer it back to the original workspace to regain access to the issues. Issues can be exported as a zip file or migrated to Jira."
How can I transfer a repository "back" so that I would have a Bitbucket issue tracker?

As I did not get an answer here, I posted my question on the Atlassian forum. And I got this answer:

Unfortunately, there are no features to revert to the old workspace. Instead, I suggest you use Jira as it has a free plan that can be utilised up to 10 users.


Check them out at:


https://www.atlassian.com/software/jira/pricing

Reference: https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/How-can-I-re-enable-Bitbucket-issues-in-an-Atlassian-workspace/qaq-p/2805870#M107530
